# SQL convert numeric 0 to text 000 in a case when statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm in management studio trying to write a query on a numeric field using a case when that looks like this:

```sql
select
case
when table1.copay*100 = 0 then '000' else table1.copay*100 end as copay
from table 1
```

I've tried all sorts of casting, padding, convert to get it to display 000 when table1.copay*100 = 0 but no matter what I try it brings back just 0. I know that's because it's a number, but I've tried converting to a string with no success.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your mixing data types.   Decide if you want a string or a numeric

Comment: Then is something for your presentation layer, not the SQL. A `CASE` **expression** can only return a scalar value, and the data type of that value will be determined by data type precedence. The expression `table1.copay*100` is going to return a numerical value of some kind, of `'000'` will be converted to the same data type, and numerical values don't have leading zeroes.

Comment: Can I somehow convert everything to a string? There isn't going to be a separate presentation layer, it's just going to save a csv and get sftp'd somewhere.

Comment: why do you need to do this table1.copay*100 = 0 to check if zero, only zero will return zero after been multiplied (at least at euclidean maths). Why dont you check zero without the multiplication?

Comment: One option is format(copay*100 ,'000')   this will return a string.  HOWEVER, it should be used sparingly due to performance issues.

Comment: Definitily this should be done at program layer for performance issues.

Comment: that worked like a charm and it's a small dataset so performance isn't an issue:One option is format(copay*100 ,'000') this will return a string. HOWEVER, it should be used sparingly due to performance issues. – 
John Cappelletti
 4 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

[John Cappelletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127927/sql-convert-numeric-0-to-text-000-in-a-case-when-statement/70128074#comment123966526_70127927) answered the question:

> One option is format(copay*100 ,'000') this will return a string. HOWEVER, it should be used sparingly due to performance issues.